# Github Actions run locally (nektos/act) how to change github.com url to pull repo from another repository

Tags: github-actions, act

I would like to run netos/act locally by using my own organization repo URL

Current default URL is https://github.com, 
In my case my organization maintains a different repository (https://ghe.XXXX.com). 
Is there any way to change the github URL locally?